# How to find Approximate Similarity between two images using Opencv in Java

Tags: java, opencv

I have Several Images in a folder and I want to find out the percentage of Similarities matching those images with a target image. How can I do that using Opencv in Java?

Comment: Can you provide me full source code that will check similarity between two Images. I badly need the source code !!! @User404

Comment: strongly depends on how you define "similarity" ...

Comment: You're asking for a complete software product from everything but the most bare basic idea through the engineering and architecture, back down to the source code. SO is a Q&A website, not a "freesoftware4u" website. If you're so interested in that, find a freelancer (not on this website) and pay for it.